# What do the white and green colours on the earth leakage CB denote?

Tags: earth, leakage-current, circuit-breaker

I've come  across two 4 pole earth leakage circuit breakers, one with the all green lever and another with white levers for phases and green for neutral. Is there any special meaning to this?

I've attached pictures to illustrate exactly which devices I'm referring to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Green is usually the color used to indicate protective earth, so I would assume in the first case that you'd put the three phase wires into the white ones and the earth wire in the green one.

Comment: 1. The customary colors might depend what country you are in, so please share that. 2. This might get better answers on [home improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) (even though it's "home improvement" there do seem to be some electricians there who would be familiar with commercial or industrial installations)